# Integration of the product of two polynomials

Tags: integration, polynomials

Consider this integration:

$$\int (x-\mu_x)^2  \cdot (mx+q) dx$$

I can square the first element, do the products and then integrate but I was wondering, is there a smarter way to perform this integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is.

$$mx+q=m(x-\mu_x)+(m\mu_x+q)$$ and an antiderivative is

$$m\frac{(x-\mu_x)^4}{4}+(m\mu_x+q)\frac{(x-\mu_x)^3}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int (x-\mu_x)^2  \cdot (mx+q) dx$$
Substitute $z=x-\mu_x$:
$$I=\int z^2  (m(z+\mu_x)+q) dz$$
$$I=\int   mz^3+(m\mu_x+q)z^2)dz$$
It's a polynomial.